# object has no attribute python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enum

Хочу сделать следующее:

Сделать enum, значениями которого будут объекты. Как я понял это возможно. Впоследствии я собираюсь их использовать для определения элементов этого enum.

сначала я сделал так

```
class Genre(Enum):
    undefined = (0, [])
    pop = (1, ["Поп и Эстрада"])
```

ide не выдаёт ошибок, значит мы можем.

```
for i in Genre:
    print(i)
```

Тоже работает.

Осталось понять, как мы можем к этому обращаться. Не мудрствуя лукаво делаю класс, пишу его в элементы enum, пытаюсь

```
from enum import Enum

class GenreItem:
    def __init__(self, id, values):
        self.id = id
        self.values = values
    
class Genre(Enum):
    undefined = GenreItem(0, [])
    pop = GenreItem(1, ["Поп и Эстрада"])


for i in Genre:
    i.__class__ = GenreItem
    print(i.id + " " + i.values)
```

получаю ошибку

> AttributeError: 'GenreItem' object has no attribute 'id'

То есть интерпретатор проглотил засечивание класса элементу enum, работает перечисление, работает каст, но, видите ли У НЕГО НЕТ АТРИБУТА id. Так есть же!

Как можно сделать так, чтобы это работало?

или как можно сделать задуманное, если не этим путём, то каким либо другим?

Comment: А что такое `засечивание`?

Comment: set по простому. Факт присваивания значения полю/аттрибуту/члену

Comment: нее... не похоже :) исправьте на `присваивание`. А `set` это множество (попробуйте `print(set('11232'))`), единственное что похожее это `setter`

Comment: У меня в личной жизни Java просто )) ок

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
from enum import Enum

class GenreItem:
    def __init__(self, id, values):
        self.id = id
        self.values = values

class Genre(Enum):
    undefined = GenreItem(0, [])
    pop = GenreItem(1, ["Поп и Эстрада"])

for i in Genre:
    item = i.value
    print(item.id, item.values)
```

Консоль:

```
0 []
1 ['Поп и Эстрада']
```

У вас в `i` будет лежать объект `Genre.undefined` или `Genre.undefined`.

А чтобы получить `GenreItem` нужно вызывать `.value`

---

> сначала я сделал так

В этом случае:

```
class Genre(Enum):
    undefined = (0, [])
    pop = (1, ["Поп и Эстрада"])

for i in Genre:
    id, values = i.value
    print(id, values)
```

В элементы вы положили кортеж (`tuple`), поэтому когда использовали `id, values = i.value`, то получили тот кортеж и разложили его по переменным. Круглые скобки, кст, можно не указывать (например `undefined = 0, []`)

---

> Как можно сделать так, чтобы это работало?

А тут хоть вы и поменяли атрибут `__class__`, но данные, а точнее атрибуты `id` и `values` все-равно лежат в другом месте, поэтому и не сработало:

```
for i in Genre:
    i.__class__ = GenreItem
    print(i.id + " " + i.values)
```

Но можно сделать один трюк, следите за кодом:

```
for i in Genre:
    i.__dict__.update(i.value.__dict__)
    print(i.id, i.values)
```

Консоль:

```
0 []
1 ['Поп и Эстрада']
```

Answer (score 0):

Ага, всё оказалось проще

```
class Genre(Enum):
    undefined = (0, [])
    pop = (1, ["Поп и Эстрада"])

for i in Genre:
    id, values = i.value
    print(id, values)
```

Только вопрос, почему не было атрибута - в силе